# How to Solve This PDE and Deal with Boundary Value Using Method of Characteristics. Work Shown.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, vector-analysis, characteristics

> The function $u(x,y)$ satisfies $u_y + u_x = 0$ in $x > 0$, $y > 0$ together with the initial condition $u(x, 0) = \sin(x)$, $x > 0$ and the boundary condition $u(0, y) = \sin(y)$, $y > 0$. Determine the values of $u$ in the whole quarter plane $x > 0$, $y > 0$.

My problem is that, although I think I know how to use the initial condition, I don't know how to use the boundary condition?

The characteristic equations are

$$\frac{dy}{dt} = 1, \frac{dx}{dt} = 1, \frac{du}{dt} = 0$$

Writing the initial condition parametrically (parameterising $t = 0$ as the initial condition), we get

$$\Gamma = \Gamma(s) = (x_0(s)), y_0(s), u_0(s)) = (s, 0, \sin(s))$$

The curve $\Gamma$ is called the initial curve.

$\therefore \frac{\partial y(t, s)}{\partial t} = 1, \frac{\partial x(t, s)}{\partial t} = 1, \frac{\partial u(t, s)}{\partial t} = 0$

with initial conditions

$$y = t + C_1(s)$$
$$\therefore y(0, s) = C_1(s) = 0$$

$$x = t + C_2(s)$$
$$\therefore x(0, s) = C_2(s) = s$$

$$u(0, s) = C_3(s) = \sin(s)$$

So our solution is given by

$$x(t, s) = t + s, y(t, s) = t, u(t, s) = \sin(s)$$

I'm not sure entirely sure how to do this, and my textbooks don't discuss how to use method of characteristics to solve problems that have initial conditions *and* boundary values. I would be very grateful for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solutions to the PDE $u_x +  u_y = 0$ are functions that are constant in the $(1,1)$ direction.

Recall how you use the initial data $u_0$ to define the solution: for any point $(x,y)$ you follow the characteristic line back to the initial condition at $y=0$ (so the point $(x-y,0)$), and since it was constant along the characteristic, the answer is $u(x,y) = u_0(x-y)$. Since the initial data is defined on $[0,\infty)$, can do this for all points $x\ge y$ i.e. points below or on the line $y=x$.

Now have a look at this graph of the boundary condition, initial condition and characteristic lines-
[image]

How would you now define the values of the solution above the $y=x$ line?

---

(Full solution.) It seems that you don't have any issue using just the "initial condition", i.e. the points $\color{red}{\{(x,0): x\ge 0\}}$. You can also use the "boundary data" i.e. the points $\color{blue}{\{(0,y): y\ge 0\}}$ to define the full "initial curve"

$$ \Gamma = \color{blue}{\{ (0,y, u_{\text{bdry}}(y)) : y\ge 0 \}} \cup  \color{red}{\{ (x,0, u_{\text{init}}(x)) : x\ge 0\}} $$ 
You can parameterise this using $s\in\mathbb R$,
$$ \Gamma(s) = 
\begin{cases} 
(s,0, \color{red}{u_{\text{init}}(s)}) & s\in [0,\infty) \\   
(0,-s, \color{blue}{u_{\text{bdry}}(-s)}) & s\in (-\infty,0]
\end{cases}$$
with a compatability condition $\color{red}{u_{\text{init}}(0)} = \color{blue}{u_{\text{bdry}}(0)}$.

Now, we implement the method of characteristics. To find the characteristic curves $(x,y) = (x(t),y(t))$, we solve
$$ \frac{d}{dt} u(x(t),y(t)) = 0$$
Of course, $ \frac{d}{dt} u(x(t),y(t)) = u_x(x(t)) x'(t) + u_y(y(t)) y'(t) $ so we just need $x'(t) = y'(t) = 1$. Thus all characteristic curves are given by
$$ (x(t),y(t)) = (x_0,y_0) + (t,t) , \quad t\geq t_0 $$
where $t_0$ is the time we leave the set $\Gamma$. Using the same parameter $s$ as before, we determine $t_0$ using $x_0=x_0(s),y_0=y_0(s)$,
\begin{align} s\ge 0 &\implies x_0 = s,y_0 = 0, t_0 = 0 \\
 s<0 &\implies x_0 = 0, y_0 = -s, t_0 = -s\end{align}

and the full solution is $$u(s,t) = u(x(s,t),y(s,t)) = \begin{cases} \color{red}{u_{\text{init}}(s)} & s\ge 0, t\ge 0 \\ \color{blue}{u_{\text{bdry}}(-s)} & s < 0, t>-s \end{cases}$$

We have defined the solution on the set $\{ (s,t) : s \in \mathbb R, t \ge \max(-s,0) \} $, and they are related to $x,y$ by
$$x = s+t , y=t $$
So that $s = x-y$,
and it should be clear that this defines the region $x\geq 0$ and $y\ge 0$. In particular $\color{red}{x>y>0}$ iff $\color{red}{s>0}$, and $\color{blue}{y>x>0}$ iff $\color{blue}{s<0}$. Therefore, the answer in the original coordinates is
$$ u(x,y) = \begin{cases} \color{red}{u_{\text{init}}(x-y)} & 0\le y\le x \\ \color{blue}{u_{\text{bdry}}(y-x)} & 0 \le x<y\end{cases}$$

---

(Final remark.) There are many different ways to write this down. However, the graph above captures the main idea that has to be expressed by all proofs of this fact. Regardless of whichever proof you learn, my opinion is that you should make sure that your understanding matches the graph.

Comment: I would say that the values of the solution above the $y = x$ line first intersect the $y$-axis, so I would use the condition $u(0, y) = \sin(y)$? I guess, in this case, these would be classified as the "initial condition" for those lines? Not sure if I'm on the right track here.

Comment: @handler'shandle Yes, exactly. The "boundary condition" is nothing more than an initial condition specified along a different curve.

Comment: Oh wow, just as I edited! I didn't think I was right, haha.

Comment: @handler'shandle :) I think you should be able to solve the rest of the problem now

Comment: So would we define a second parameterisation? If I'm not mistaken, $\Gamma = \Gamma(s) = (x_0(s)), y_0(s), u_0(s)) = (s, 0, \sin(s))$ is just along the bottom line?

Comment: @handler'shandle I think the current one is fine, an initial condition for an ODE does not /need/ to be at $t=0$.

Comment: Hmm, I still don't understand the process to solve this. It seems to me like we need 2 solutions, which means that I need to repeat the process above twice, once for the initial condition and again for the boundary condition?

Comment: Maybe I don't understand what you mean by parameterisation. You can arrange it into as many processes as you want, but there's 'only one' thing you need to do, which is to travel backwards along a characteristic until you hit a value you already know.

Comment: For $u_0(s) = \sin(s)$ in $\Gamma = \Gamma(s) = (x_0(s)), y_0(s), u_0(s)) = (s, 0, \sin(s))$, I used the initial condition $u(x, 0) = \sin(x)$. So it seems that I have to repeat this process for the second solution using $u(0, y) = \sin(y)$? I can't find any resources that have examples with initial conditions, so I have no idea what I'm supposed to do.

Comment: It seems like you do understand it but are unsure. I think you really do get it. But some pedantic points - One, It's all just one solution $u$. Two, you already repeat this once for each point $(x,y)$ with $y\le x$. So I'm not so sure why you think it's any different to continue doing this for the points $y>x$. You can find this in full generality in Evans where he defines what kinds of hypersurfaces you can use as initial data but he does it more generally than the 2D case.

Comment: I found some really good lectures online that I'm currently reading: https://sites.ualberta.ca/~aksikas/math337-cha2.pdf

Comment: I am writing notes now and will edit my main post with my new work when I'm done. :)

Comment: @handler'shandle I have added a full solution.

Comment: Thank you again for such an excellent answer! I spent a hours researching and writing down every detail of this, so I learned a lot. One question: I read that the solution $u$ is supposed to vary exponentially along the characteristics. In our case, isn't $u$ varying sinusoidally along the characteristics?

Comment: @handler'shandle no to both, the solution is *constant* along characteristics.

Comment: This is from page 39 of *Essential Partial Differential Equations* by Griffiths, Dold, and Silvester: "$x = py + k, u = A(k)e^y$. Thus the characteristics are simply straight lines along which $u$ varies exponentially. The parameter $k$ may be eliminated to give the general solution directly in terms of $x$ and $y$:"

Comment: @handler'shandle I bet it is solving a different equation.

Comment: It is solving $pux +quy = f$. So the behaviour of the solution along the characteristic varies depending on the equation?

Comment: @handler'shandle yes, this is the effect of the term $f$.

Comment: Ahh, ok. Thank you again!

Comment: @handler'shandle you're welcome!